# nested enum in c# and classes

Tags: c#, class, enums

I heard that nesting of `enum` is not possible in C#. Then how can convert the following structure to a class hierarchy or something else. So I want the class to act as an `enum`

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far ? does it work ? if no, what is it supposed to do ?

Comment: Do you mean an enum or an enumerable? The above looks more like something that would be modelled by an enumerable than by an enum.

Comment: This question it's old, but I made a suggestion (on roslyn github project) to implement this feature in next versions of C# http://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13192

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nested classes and const fields

```
class Cat1
{
    public const int Public = 1;
    public class Private
    {
        public const int Abc = 2;
        public const int Mno = 3;
        public const int Pqr = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting the variable would just be an `int`, so could get given an invalid value from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Cat1
{
  public enum Publicpart
  {
     Xyz
  }

  private enum Privatepart
  {
     Abc, Mno, Pqr
  }
}
```

then you can call it like this

```
Cat1.Publicpart.Xyz
```

or if you have private acces

```
Cat1.Privatepart.Abc
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the hirerchy as class structure , which every class has a property of its own of enum

Answer (score 1):

You should rethink if you want to solve this problems via enums because the first enum category represents to me some kind of "visibility" concept while the second category is only valid of instances with visibility "public".

What about solving your issue with something like this:

```
public enum Visibility
{
    Public,
    Private
}

public abstract class VisibilityState
{
    public Visibility Visibility { get; private set; }

    protected VisibilityState(Visibility visibility)
    {
        Visibility = visibility;
    }
}

public class PublicVisibilityState : VisibilityState
{
    public PublicVisibilityState() : base(Visibility.Public) { }
}

public class PrivateVisibilityState : VisibilityState
{
    public PrivateVisibilityState() : base(Visibility.Private) { }
    public OtherEnum OtherEnumState { get; set; }
}

public enum OtherEnum
{
    Abc, Mno, Pqr
}
```